# How can I access directories from internal server from corporate intranet page?

Tags: file, local, directory, intranet

I am somewhat new to web page design and am working on my company's internal web site. I have been requested to construct pages that display content from our internal servers in a more presentable way. Unfortunately I am running into trouble accessing these directories from the site. Ideally what I would like to do is access the relevant directory based on its UNC, display the contents as links on a php page, and open the files locally (not download) via the links. I understand there are certain restrictions in doing this but as close to what I described as possible would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You can use php to list the folder content (opendir() + readdir()) then print links the files within this directory (providing the UNC path).